# Spring boot application gives "unable to start tomcat" exception with spring-boot-starter-actuator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I had my spring-boot application, with spring-boot-starter-web, then I added spring-boot-starter-actuator to gradle file. There is no compilation error. But when i try to run the server it gives the following exception.

my build.gradle content (only the main ones included )

```
plugins {
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
} ...........

compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
compile group: 'io.micrometer', name: 'micrometer-registry-prometheus', version: '1.1.3'  .........
```

my application.properties content

```
server.port = 2128

spring.couchbase.env.timeouts.connect=10000

spring.couchbase.env.timeouts.query=180000

spring.couchbase.env.timeouts.view=20000

spring.couchbase.bootstrap-hosts=localhost

spring.couchbase.bucket.name=localdb

spring.couchbase.bucket.password=*****

spring.data.couchbase.repositories.type=auto

spring.data.couchbase.auto-index=true

server.compression.enabled=true

server.compression.mime-types=application/json,text/plain

spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true

spring.servlet.multipart.maxFileSize=50MB

spring.servlet.multipart.maxRequestSize=50MB
```

my Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Gives the following exception while starting the server.

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server;            
nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource 
WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed;    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource 
org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 1; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthIndicatorRegistry' defined in class path resource  [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed
```

Any helpful hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to start the application after I turned off default health checks via the following entry in application.properties file

```
management.health.defaults.enabled=false
```